# Populate Power Apps Combo Box Selection with Value from Another SharePoint List

Tags: combobox, powerapps, power-platform

Combobox1 in the Job Leader Change Request Power App pulls from Source_JobInfo SharePoint list.

When the user clicks the submit button,

- Patch() is triggered so the combo box selection and all the other fields in the form are written to Form_ChangeRequest SharePoint list.
- Power App closes [Exit()], which wipes out the form.
- Approver clicks a button [workflow.Run()] which contains URL for to Power App noted above and a unique parameter which passes to a variable.  Power apps uses Lookups and the variable to populate the fields in the Power App form so that the approver may review the form submitted in the example above.

I have not been able to populate the combo box with the selection made by the originator of the form.  The combo box pulls from one list and writes the selection to another.  I attempted a lookup/variable in the DefaultSelectedItem, but could not get it to work.

I thought that I could pass the Leader Name value in a variable used to match the leader name in the original Combo Box source list.

LookUp(Source_JobInfo, Project Leaderer=varLeadName)

That did not work.